# Let $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\frac1x-\frac 1y|$. Prove that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\frac1x-\frac 1y|$. Prove that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent in $(0,1)$

### First proof

Check the validity of the proof please. Im interested in easier or simpler proofs too, if exists.

Two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ over some set $X$ are defined as equivalent if and only if

$$(\forall x\in X)(\forall \epsilon >0)(\exists r,s>0):(B_1(x,r)\subseteq B_2(x,\epsilon))\land (B_2(x,s)\subseteq B_1(x,\epsilon))$$

where $B_j(x,\epsilon):=\{y\in X: d_j(x,y)<\epsilon\}$ are open balls.

**Part one:** for all $x,y\in(0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0$ we have that

$$\begin{align}B_1(x,r)\subseteq B_2(x,\epsilon)&\iff |x-y|<r\implies \left|\frac1x-\frac 1y\right|<\epsilon\\&\iff |x-y|<r\implies|x-y|<xy\epsilon\\&\iff r\le xy\epsilon\end{align}$$

*Case 1:* if $1>x\epsilon$ and cause $|\frac1x-\frac1y|<\epsilon$ then we have that

$$\left|\frac1x-\frac1y\right|<\epsilon\implies\begin{cases}\frac1y>\frac1x-\epsilon,&\text{if } \frac1y<\frac1x\\\frac1y<\frac1x+\epsilon,&\text{if }\frac1y\ge \frac1x\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}y<\frac{x}{1-x\epsilon},&\text{if }y>x\\y>\frac{x}{1+x\epsilon},&\text{if }y<x\end{cases}$$

in any case $y$ is bounded below positively because $x>0$, what means that $\inf\{xy:x,y\in(0,1)\}\neq 0$. Then exists some $r>0$ such that $r\le xy\epsilon$, i.e.

$$(\forall x\in (0,1))(\forall\epsilon\in(0,x))(\exists r\in\Bbb R_{>0}):B_1(x,r)\subseteq B_2(x,\epsilon)$$

*Case 2:* If $1<x\epsilon$ then we can set some $\delta>0$ such that $1>x\delta$, reducing this case to the above case, i.e.

$$B_1(x,r)\subseteq B_2(x,\delta)\subsetneq B_2(x,\epsilon)$$

**Part two:** for all $x,y\in(0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0$ we have that

$$\begin{align}B_2(x,s)\subseteq B_1(x,\epsilon)&\iff \left|\frac1x-\frac 1y\right|<s\implies |x-y|<\epsilon\\&\iff |x-y|<xys\implies|x-y|<\epsilon\\&\iff xys\le \epsilon\implies s\le\epsilon\end{align}$$

because $\sup\{xy:x,y\in(0,1)\}=1$. Then setting $s=\epsilon$ we have that

$$B_2(x,\epsilon)\subseteq B_1(x,\epsilon),\quad\forall\epsilon>0,\forall x\in(0,1)$$

And with this the proof ends.

---

### Second proof

The open balls of $d_1$ have the form

$$B_1(x,s)=(x-s,x+s)\cap(0,1)$$

The open balls of $d_2$ have the form

$$B_2(x,r)=\left\{y\in(0,1):\left|\frac1x-\frac 1y\right|<r\right\}\implies \frac1y\in\left(\frac1x-r,\frac1x+r\right)$$

then

$$y\in\left(\frac{1-rx}{x},\frac{1+rx}{x}\right)^{-1}=\begin{cases}\left(\frac{x}{1+rx},\frac{x}{1-rx}\right)&\text{if }\frac1x>r\\\left(\frac{x}{1-rx},\infty\right)\cap(0,1)&\text{if }\frac1x<r\end{cases}$$

[From here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2F(1%2Brx)%3Ex-s+%26%26+x%2F(1-rx)%3Cx%2Bs+%26%26+r%3E0+%26%26+s%3E0+%26%26+0%3Cx%3C1+for+r) we can check that exists solutions for $B_2(x,r)\subseteq B_1(x,s)$ for any $x\in(0,1)$ and any $s>0$.

[And exists solutions too](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2F(1%2Brx)%3Cx-s+%26%26+x%2F(1-rx)%3Ex%2Bs+%26%26+r%3E0+%26%26+s%3E0+%26%26+0%3Cx%3C1+for+s) for $B_1(x,r)\subseteq B_2(x,s)$ for any $x\in(0,1)$ and any $s>0$.

Comment: In the first part, it should be: $|x-y|<r\implies|x-y|<xy\epsilon$ if and only if $r\leq xy\epsilon$. You made the same mistake in the second part too.

Comment: @user105013 ah, you are right. I will change it. Thank you.

Comment: @Masacroso: Although i have not read your solution but i think the point here is that $x \to \frac {1}{x}$ is a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ and you are just pulling back the metric from $(1,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$ under the homeomorphism.

Comment: In my opinion, you can simplify your approach at the first part - it certainly seems like an overkill. If you want hints from different proofs, I can think of finding a metric d3 such that d1 is equivalent to it and $d1 \prec d2 \prec d3$; remember that when a metric d1 is equivalent to a metric d3 and $d1 \prec d2 \prec d3$, then d1, d2 and d3 are equivalent.