# Prove $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$ are equivalent metrics

Tags: metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

I am trying to prove whether $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$ are equivalent metrics or not. Both metrics are defined in the same space $E=\mathbb{R}^+$.

We can check they are not strongly equivalent: $d_2(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|=|\frac{y-x}{xy}|=\frac{|x-y|}{|xy|}\nleq M|x-y|=Md_1(x,y)$, as $|xy|$ can be $<1$ or $>1$ and $M$ has to be a positive constant $\forall x,y\in E$.

I don't succeed proving equivalence. I am trying to prove that, given $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $x\in E,\ \exists s\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $B_s(x,d_1)\subseteq B_r(x,d_2)$, where these $B$ are open balls centered in $x$ (and also proving that $B_{s'}(x',d_2)\subseteq B_{r'}(x',d_1)$ given $x'\in E$ and $r'\in\mathbb{R}^+$). Attempt:

$$B_s(x,d_1)=\lbrace y\in\mathbb{R}:d_1(x,y)<s\rbrace=\lbrace y\in\mathbb{R}:|x-y|<s\rbrace=\lbrace y\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{|x-y|}{|xy|}<\frac{s}{|xy|}\rbrace=\lbrace y\in\mathbb{R}:d_2(x,y)<\frac{s}{|xy|}\rbrace$$

But I don't know how to continue. Could you help me? Is there a faster/easier way to prove it? [This proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963205/let-d-1x-y-x-y-and-d-2x-y-frac1x-frac-1y-prove-that-d-1-and-d) uses $E=(0,1)$. Is that because $d_1$ and $d_2$ are only equivalent in this interval? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question does not makes sense unless the space $E$ is specified in adavance.

Comment: What does $-$ mean? What does $1/x$ mean? What does $|\cdot |$ mean?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $E=\mathbb{R}$. I think they are not equivalent in this $E$, but I would like some rigurous proof.

Comment: The second metric is not even defined on $E =\mathbb  R$. @Gibbs

Comment: The second metric is not even defined for $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.

Comment: My fault, $E=\mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $d _1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent iff the following condition holds: For $(x_n) \subset E, x \in E$ we have $d_1(x_n,x) \to 0$ iff $d_1(x_n,x) \to 0$

Comment: Well, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence such that $x_n\neq0\ \forall n$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=L\neq0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x_n}=\frac{1}{L}$, and as $0\notin E$, then $d_1(x_n,x)\to0$ iff $d_2(x_n,x)\to0$, so both metrics are equivalent on $E$. Furthermore, they are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace$. Am I right?

Comment: @Gibbs You are absolutely right.