# Question about missing steps in a topology proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was looking over this proof here [Let $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\frac1x-\frac 1y|$. Prove that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent in $(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963205/let-d-1x-y-x-y-and-d-2x-y-frac1x-frac-1y-prove-that-d-1-and-d)

Can someone explain why the step in case 2 of the first proof reduces to the previous case? Is it something to do with how delta is found?

Comment: If you look at your main logical statement $(\forall x\in X)(\forall \epsilon >0)\dots\dots$, even though you must handle arbitrary positive epsilon, it causes no problem to replace epsilon given to you by an even smaller one. (In this case the new epsilon =delta, small enough with repsect to x and 1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the proof you are studying is not good for pedagogical purpose because it is only manipulating quantificators. Let me give what I claim to be a more natural proof.

First note that what you are calling equivalent metrics is more precisely the topological equivalence of metrics. There is another (stronger and here not realized) meaning for $d_1,d_2$ to be equivalent which is
$$
\exists c_1,c_2 > 0,\quad \forall x,y \in (0,1),\quad c_2d_1(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y) \leq c_2d_1(x,y).
$$
So what you want to show is $\tau_{d_1} = \tau_{d_2}$ where $\tau_d$ stands for the topology generated by the metric $d$.

On the one hand, if $U \subset (0,1)$ is an open subset for $d_1$, you want to show that $U$ is an open set for $d_2$. So let me show you it is sequentially open, which is enough because your topology derives from a metric. If $(x_j)$ is a sequence of $(0,1)$ that goes to $x_\infty \in U$ for the metric $d_2$, you have that
$$
\left \lvert \frac{1}{x_j} - \frac{1}{x_\infty} \right \rvert \longrightarrow 0
$$
where the limit is taken with the standard topology on $(0,\infty)$. But the map $\phi : x \longmapsto 1/x$ is a homeomorphism from $(0,\infty)$ to itself endowed of the standard metric. Thus the last convergence exactly tells you that
$$
\phi(x_j) \longrightarrow \phi(x_\infty)
$$
for the standard metric on $(0,\infty)$ and thus
$$
x_j \longrightarrow x_\infty
$$
for the standard metric on $(0,\infty)$. Actually, as the sequence takes it values in $U$ which is sequentially open for the standard metric $d_1$ you know that
$$
\exists N \in \mathbb N,\quad \forall j \geq N,\quad x_j \in U.
$$
Hence $U$ is sequentially open for $d_2$.

On the other hand if $U$ is open for $d_2$ the same proof as above but with $(d_1,d_2,\phi)$ replaced with $(d_2,d_1,\phi^{-1})$ tells you that $U$ is also open for $d_1$ which ends the proof.

Note that we only used the fact that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Note also that we could have replaced our use of open sets by converging sequences. More precisely it was enough to show that $((0,1) , d_1)$ and $((0,1) , d_2)$ have the same converging sequences: forall $(x_j)$ sequence of $(0,1)$ and $x_\infty \in (0,1)$, the sequence goes to $x_\infty$ for $d_1$ if and only if this happens for $d_2$.